# STM32F4 USB CDC, can't use Data with pyserial

Tags: python, usb, stm32, pyserial, cdc

I have a problem with the combination of STM32F4 USB CDC and pyserial. If my Code in the STM32 wants to work with the received Data in the main.c I can't open the Port. If not, I can send and receive with no problem, the information is stored successfully in the UserRxBufferFS.

I get following error:

```
>>> ser.open() Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 78, in open
    self._reconfigure_port()   File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 222, in
_reconfigure_port
    'Original message: {!r}'.format(ctypes.WinError())) serial.serialutil.SerialException: Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: WindowsError(87, 'Falscher Parameter.')
```

I tried to store the Data in a global variable that I declared in the usbd_cdc_if.h:

usbd_cdc_if.h: `extern int my_buf[8];`
usbd_cdc_if.c: `my_buf[0]=UserRxBufferFS[0];`

--> error

Tried to call a function in the callback that brings the information to my main.c --> error

Tried a global pointer that points to the buffer --> error

All of this is working when I use a windows terminal. 
But I need to use pyserial. When I don't work with the data I can connect, send and receive everything with no problem.

Has anyone an idea of the problem and a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

> WindowsError(87, 'Falscher Parameter.')

I suppose you know that means 'wrong parameter'. Did you send an invalid parameter to the routine?

Note that, very probably, `UserRxBufferFS` will be defined as something like an `unsigned char` (1 byte long) because the communication is byte by byte. You are defining your buffer as `int`, which probably is either 2 or 4 bytes long.

Maybe you as passing `int` to the transmission or initializing routine, where that routine expects bytes? (or `unsigned char`s)

```
my_buf[0]=UserRxBufferFS[0];
```

transfers the first element from `UserRxBufferFS` to `my_buf`, which probably copies an `unsigned char` into an `int`, which can also give unexpected results.